# Searchkick what is the syntax to query with DateTime

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using the [gem searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) and I would like to do a query like this: `Product.where("products.created_at  < products.distribution_ended_at")` in the search method of searchkick

Here is my model Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

searchkick word_start: [:name]

def search_data
    {
            name:           name,
            content:        content,
            amount:         amount,
            created_at:     created_at,
            distribution_ended_at: distribution_ended_at
    }


  end


end
```

Here is my products controller

```
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    
        def index
    
            @products = Product.all
    
            search_conditions = {
                created_at: {lt: distribution_ended_at}
              }
    
            sort_conditions =[]
    
        aggregations = {}
    
        @product  = Product.new
        @products = Product.search("*", aggs: aggregations, where: search_conditions,
          page: params[:page], per_page: 20, match: :word_start, order: sort_conditions)

        end
end
```

But the thing is, that doesn't find `distribution_ended_at`

Anyone has an idea how to write this query in the search conditions of Searchkick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `distribution_ended_at` might equal to `nil`. Try:

```
search_conditions = {
  created_at: { lt: params[:distribution_ended_at] }
}
```